# Find Customers are in only One Subscription

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like below. Let's call it table1.

| ID | Subscription |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | A |
| 101 | B |
| 101 | C |
| 102 | A |
| 103 | A |
| 103 | B |
| 104 | D |

I would like to get the IDs of:

1. Customers have ONLY Subscription A
2. Customers with Subscription A

Bucket 1 would be = 102

Bucket 2 would be = 101, 102, 103

Note! ID=104 would not be in any bucket because it does not have Subscription A.

How can I get two lists with Bucket1 IDs? AKA IDs with only Subscription A. Note, Subscription are just examples. They are multiple Subscriptions.

The expected output could be a temporary table with only one column which has the IDs from Bucket1.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @forpas The expected output could be two temporary tables with only one column which has the IDs from bucket1 and bucket2.

Comment: Fix: bucket 2 would be 101,102,103

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope mine is readable/understandable.
[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c47992/7)

bucket 1:

```
select distinct id from docs as d1
where d1.id in (select id from docs where id=d1.id and subscription='A')
  and not exists (select id from docs where id=d1.id and subscription!='A')
```

bucket 2:

```
select distinct id from docs
where id in (select id from docs where subscription='A');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `ID`s with only subscription `'A'` if they don't have any other subscription:

```
SELECT ID
FROM tablename
GROUP BY ID
HAVING SUM(Subscription <> 'A') = 0;
```

Assuming that the combination of `ID` and `Subscription` is unique, like your sample data, for the `ID`s with subscription `'A'` and any other subscription it's simple:

```
SELECT ID
FROM tablename
WHERE Subscription = 'A';
```

There is no need for `DISTINCT`.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ed7d44055284c6bf122509ca590b159a).

Answer (score 0):

We can use aggregation here.  For customers with only subscription A:

```
SELECT ID
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ID
HAVING MIN(Subscription) = MAX(Subscription) AND
       MIN(Subscription) = 'A';
```

For customers having subscription A possibly with other subscriptions as well:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ID
FROM yourTable
WHERE Subscripion = 'A';
```

Comment: I updated the question. Subscriptions are just a placeholder. They are not A, B, C, etc.

Comment: Your sample data table appears to remain the same.  In any case, the general premise to my answer won't change.